# using multiple phidgets imus

Tags: ros, phidgets

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and am trying to use multiple Phidgets IMU's simultaneously. One IMU works great but it seems like modifications would need to be made in order to read from multiple IMUs simultaneously. What is the best way to approach this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258194/using-multiple-phidgets-imus/) by [bradbur](https://answers.ros.org/users/29862/bradbur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try launching your nodes (or entire launch file) under a different namespace. That allows you to start multiple instances without needing to make any modifications to the nodes or their launch files.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0